# Is commutation preserved for $e^A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $A, B \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$. Suppose $A$ commutes with $B$. Does $e^A$ necessarily commute with $B$?

If that is the case, consider $$S = A + B \exp(-S)$$ where $S$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Does $S$ necessarily commute with $A$?

Comment: Yes. Also, if $A = P^{-1}J P,$ then $e^A = P^{-1} \; e^J \; P \; , \;$ which is one reason for the importance of the Jordan Normal Form

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you. I have added a new note in my question. Will appreciate your comment

Comment: @vyaman Are you saying $S$ is the solution to that equation?

Comment: @user76284 yes, and I have now fixed the equation in my question

Comment: Formally, $e^A B = (I + A + \frac{1}{2} A^2 + \cdots) B = B + BA + \frac{1}{2} B A^2 + \cdots = B + AB + \frac{1}{2} A^2 B + \cdots = B (I + A + \frac{1}{2} A^2 + \cdots) = B e^A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, for any analytic function $f$ on a neighbourhood of the spectrum of $A$, $f(A)$ (as defined by the holomorphic functional calculus) is a limit of rational functions of $A$, and therefore commutes with $B$.

For your second question, formally a solution is $S = A + W(B \exp(-A))$ where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  The various branches of $W$ have various branch points, but if I'm not mistaken, for every point of the complex plane there is a branch of $W$ that is analytic there.  Thus it should always be possible to produce a branch that is analytic in a neighbourhood of the spectrum of $B \exp(-A)$, and thus to produce a corresponding solution $S$.  Then since $B$ commutes with $A$, so does $S$.
I'm not sure if every possible solution $S$ must commute with $A$.

Comment: I think your last sentence is for the case where $A$ and $B$ do nott commute. Or do you think there can exist a $S$ that do not commute with $A$ while satisfying the equation and with the assumption of $A$ and $B$ do commute?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ don't commute, then certainly $S$ and $A$ can't commute, because $B = (S-A) \exp(S)$.  I'm not sure if you can have $S$ that doesn't commute with $A$ when $A$ and $B$ commute.